# How to send result only after I execute function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

json() I want to send result from function after post but I think res.json() executes before I have the result from the function and every time result is undefined.

```
Game.find({ $or: [{ 'homeTeamName': awayTeamName }, { 'awayTeamName': awayTeamName }] })
          .then(
            function (games) {
              let gamesGuest = games
              let result = testFunc.createCoef(gamesHome, gamesGuest, homeTeamName, awayTeamName)
              res.json(result)
            }
          )
          .catch(err =>
            res.status(404).json('Away no games')
          )
      }
    )
```

Comment: add a promise to `testFunc.createCoef`.....also add the code of `testFunc.createCoef` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using async await

```
Game.find({ $or: [{ 'homeTeamName': awayTeamName }, { 'awayTeamName': awayTeamName }] })
      .then(
        async function (games) {
          let gamesGuest = games
          let result = await testFunc.createCoef(gamesHome, gamesGuest, homeTeamName, awayTeamName)
          res.json(result)
        }
      )
      .catch(err =>
        res.status(404).json('Away no games')
      )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Nodejs , I'm still new to it, but I think with asynchronous execution , you can use Await , so it will wail for the function to complete and then move to the next line,

so try to add "await" before the function

```js
Game.find({ $or: [{ 'homeTeamName': awayTeamName }, { 'awayTeamName': awayTeamName }] })
          .then(
           async function (games) {
              let gamesGuest = games
              let result = await testFunc.createCoef(gamesHome, gamesGuest, homeTeamName, awayTeamName)
              res.json(result)
            }
          )
          .catch(err =>
            res.status(404).json('Away no games')
          )
      }
    )
```